AWS/Python Lambda: keep a global variable within a lambda run that's isolated from other lambda runs
The AWS lambdas doc said that global variable will be share across lambda runs. Due to legacy reason, I need to find way to declare and keep a global variable to a lambda run, and it need to be isolated from other lambda runs.
I'm was thinking using class attribute. AWS lambda still treat class attribute as global variable, right?

AWS Lambda functions run in containers. These containers might be reused on future invocations. If an environment is reused, then you can 'keep' data between invocations by using global variables. AWS Lambda might also launch multiple containers, but the variables are not shared between containers.
If you wish to use a 'global variable' but not have it accessible on future invocations, then simply clear out the value of the variable by using del before exiting the function.
You might find this series of articles interesting. They describe how Lambda functions operate: Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog

What if multiple instances of the lambda function running at the same time? Will this create a race problem? Or always one lambda instance per one container?

One Lambda per container. The container is the 'compute' and the Lambda function is the code that runs in that compute. They are totally independent and don't share any variables between each other.
